# input type="file" attribute accept not working in Safari on macbook

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="attachments">Attach a file</label>
      <input type="file" id="attachments" accept=".doc,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.pdf,.png,.xls,.xlsx,.zip" name="attachments" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works fine in chrome browser on windows, but it does not work in Safari browser of macbook.

[image]

Any ideas for this?

Comment: please, help me !!!

Comment: I hope that you don't rely on this feature to check for type of files uploaded, since anyone can change it. That being said look here to find mimetypes that are supported in Safari https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/MIMETypeRegistry.cpp

Comment: I know the user can change it, I have to check again once the file is selected, but the client asked me to do so, need the filter as soon as the client select the file, for convenient use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it seems Safari doesn't accept files' extensions as `accept` attribute...
<sup>And it could be seen as a bug since they will do the MIME detection against this exact file extension...)</sup>

The only workaround I see for now, is to use the full MIME type.
But this may lead to some problem where some browsers will use the OS's MIME types dictionary against... file's extensions.

So the best course of action here is maybe to add both MIMEs and extensions.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="attachments">Attach a file</label>
      <input type="file" id="attachments" 
        accept="application/msword,image/gif,image/jpeg,application/pdf,image/png,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/zip,.doc,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.pdf,.png,.xls,.xlsx,.zip" 
        name="attachments" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Got the MIMEs from [Apache's list](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types))

Also note that this `accept` attribute should only be there as a convenient way for users to know what kind of files are expected, and absolutely not as a way to check what file types you'll get. Your actual list seems so diversified that it makes little sense to use it.

Comment: yes,  
I know the user can change it, I have to check again once the file is selected, but the client asked me to do so, need the filter as soon as the client select the file, for convenient use.

Comment: I tried to follow you but it still does not work in safari

Comment: @TranAudi you mean that the snippet in the answer doesn't work for you? It definitely works on my Safari 11.0.1 on Sierra